# DelegateFactories don't return a new object(Unit of Work pattern)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, unit-of-work, factories

I have a factory that returns the UOW

```
 class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    private UnitOfWork.Factory factory;
    public ISession Session;
    public IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public UnitOfWorkFactory(UnitOfWork.Factory factory,
                             ISession session, IRepository repository)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.Session = session;
        Repository = repository;
    }



    public IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        return factory(Session, Repository); 
    }


}
```

The first call to the factory returns a new instance of the UOW.
However, on subsequent calls, it returns previously created instances, not the new.
I used the instructions developers "autofac" to use a [delegate factory](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories)

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    public ISession Session;
    public IRepository Repository { get; set; }
    private Transaction transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(ISession session, IRepository repository)
    {
        this.Session = session;
        Repository = repository;
        transaction = Session.Transaction;
    }



    public delegate IUnitOfWork Factory(ISession transaction,
                                        IRepository repository);



    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (transaction.IsActive)
        {
           //Rollback
        }

       Session.Dispose();

    }


    public void Commit()
    {
        transaction.Commit();
    }


}
```

Registration into IoC

```
        builder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWorkFactory>().As<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class UnitOfWork is registered as "Instance per liferime scope". Since you don't create a separate lifetime scope, current lifetime scope will be used every time you create a IUnitOfWork, and the IUnitOfWork will be created only once.

Change the registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerDependency();
```